# Data frame with duplicates in a column map to another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "col1": [11, 12, 13],
    "col2": [21, 22, 23],
    "col3": [31, 32, 33],
    "col4": [41, 42, 43],
})
```

I have a Pandas data frame like `df` above, and I would like to reshape `df` to look like the following.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({

    "col1": [11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13],
    "col2": [21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43],
    "indx": ["col2", "col2", "col2", "col3", "col3", "col3", "col4", "col4", "col4"]
})
```

I can slice up `df` and get my desired data frame, but what would be the slick, Pythonic way to do it in Pandas?

**EDIT**

I'm realizing that my question is more complicated that I originall realized, but not too much more (I think). Again, I have a data frame.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    
    "col1": [11, 12, 13],
    "col2": [21, 22, 23],
    "col3": [31, 32, 33],
    "col4": [41, 42, 43],
    "col5": [51, 52, 53],
    "col6": [61, 62, 63]
})
```

I want to do something like `melt` to get my data frame to be like this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({

    "col1": [11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13, 11, 12, 13],
    "colA": [21, 22, 23, 31, 32, 33, 41, 42, 43],
    "indx": ["do", "do", "do", "re", "re", "re", "me", "me", "me"],
    "col4": [41, 42, 43, 41, 42, 43, 41, 42, 43],
    "col5": [51, 52, 53, 51, 52, 53, 51, 52, 53],
    "col6": [61, 62, 63, 61, 62, 63, 61, 62, 63]
})
```

So I want to be able to set the strings to which the "indx" etc are set; I want to drag along several other columns the way that I drag along "col1", and I want to set the name of the new "col2" column header.

Thanks!

Comment: ```df.melt("col1", var_name="idx", value_name="col2").iloc[:, [0, -1, 1]]```

Comment: @sammywemmy That did it! Now if I want to replace the "col2" "col3" names, is there a way to do that in the same line? (I've realized that I might want "do", "re", "mi" instead of "col2", "col3", "col4".)

Comment: this part is a bit unclear. Mind sharing an example in your original question?

Comment: @sammywemmy Edited.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically what you're looking for:

```
df.set_index('col1').unstack()
```

## Output:

```
      col1
col2  11      21
      12      22
      13      23
col3  11      31
      12      32
      13      33
col4  11      41
      12      42
      13      43
```

Your column names will be indexes which seems to be what you were looking for

Answer (score 2):

You need `melt`, `merge` and `replace`

```
d = {'col2': 'do', 'col3': 're', 'col4': 'me'}

df_final = (df.melt(['col1','col5','col6'], var_name="indx", value_name="colA")
              .merge(df[['col1','col4']], how='left').replace(d))
    
Out[522]:
   col1  col5  col6 indx  colA  col4
0    11    51    61   do    21    41
1    12    52    62   do    22    42
2    13    53    63   do    23    43
3    11    51    61   re    31    41
4    12    52    62   re    32    42
5    13    53    63   re    33    43
6    11    51    61   me    41    41
7    12    52    62   me    42    42
8    13    53    63   me    43    43
```

---

Or you may `rename` columns before `melt`

```
d = {'col2': 'do', 'col3': 're', 'col4': 'me'}

df_final = (df.rename(d, axis=1)
              .melt(['col1','col5','col6'], var_name="indx", value_name="colA")
              .merge(df[['col1','col4']], how='left'))

Out[529]:
   col1  col5  col6 indx  colA  col4
0    11    51    61   do    21    41
1    12    52    62   do    22    42
2    13    53    63   do    23    43
3    11    51    61   re    31    41
4    12    52    62   re    32    42
5    13    53    63   re    33    43
6    11    51    61   me    41    41
7    12    52    62   me    42    42
8    13    53    63   me    43    43
```

Comment: @Dave: it left-joins `df.col4` to the result dataframe of `melt` by matching on values of `col1` of both dataframes

Answer (score 1):

Create a duplicate of `col4`, [melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) the data and [replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) the values :

```
(
    df.assign(temp=df.col4)
    .melt(id_vars=["col1", "col4", "col5", "col6"],
          var_name="indx",
          value_name="colA")
    .replace({"col2": "do", "col3": "re", "temp": "me"})
    .iloc[:, [0, -1, -2, 1, 2, 3]]
)

   col1 colA    indx    col4    col5    col6
0   11  21      do      41      51       61
1   12  22      do      42      52       62
2   13  23      do      43      53       63
3   11  31      re      41      51       61
4   12  32      re      42      52       62
5   13  33      re      43      53       63
6   11  41      me      41      51       61
7   12  42      me      42      52       62
8   13  43      me      43      53       63
```

Comment: good use of `assign` to create duplicate of `col4` :) +1

Comment: Thanks mate. Cheers